# Why are black holes called singularities?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities

I have researched black holes but I can't seem to find the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18981/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75619/50583 and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A black hole itself is not a singularity, but General Relativity predicts that a [singularity](http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_blackholes_singularities.html) exists at the center of a black hole.

As far as I can determine, it's called a singularity because the laws of physics cease to describe what happens there.  Curvature of space-time and density of matter become infinite.  They are undefined.  In mathematics, a [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) is an object that is undefined, or a point in a set where an object is not well-behaved.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ernie, this really helped me understand my physics homework.