# Why is a theory of quantum gravity expected to solve the BigBang singularity problem?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, string-theory, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

This a follow-up question related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387621/technically-what-is-a-spacetime-singularity-and-why-is-the-bigbang-a-singularit). A successful theory of Quantum gravity is expected to solve the BigBang singularity problem.

*Why (and how) is the quantization of gravity supposed to solve the BigBang singularity problem?*

*What is the status of String Theory and Loop Quantum Gravity in addressing this problem of classical General Relativity?*

Comment: Surely it's the case of "A successful theory of Quantum gravity is *hoped* to solve the BigBang singularity problem."?

Comment: Because it implies breakdown in classical geometric description of space at small scales, and therefore makes point singularities impossible by definition. The standard GR description emerges analogously to how description in terms of elastic waves, say, emerges from more basic description in terms of particle oscillations, it would make no sense to ask what a wave "looks like" on scales smaller than wavelength. For a discussion of how this eliminates the Big Bang see [On the Emergence of Time in Quantum Gravity by Isham and Butterfield](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9901024).