# Does a white hole forms accretion disk?

Tags: white-holes, accretion-disk, relativistic-jets

A white is time reversal of a blackhole at least mathematically, I know it can't exist but may I know if it can form accretion disc similar to those stellar mass black holes. Does it spins on it's axis and emit relativistic jets?

Comment: This may help - [What Would a White Hole Look Like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442824/37364)