# Could time dilation caused by a black hole lead to an observer falling into it observe it decaying as quickly as they fell In?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation

As you approach a black hole, time slows down for you. Is it possible for the black hole to appear to decay via Hawking radiation as quickly as you fell in? Or does the decay occur too slowly for this?

Answer (score 2):

> As you approach a black hole, time slows down for you.

Not true. Time always flows at its normal rate for you. You hit the singularity in about a millisecond in the case of a solar-mass black hole.

Related: [What will the universe look like for anyone falling into a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26185/what-will-the-universe-look-like-for-anyone-falling-into-a-black-hole) (but note that the accepted answer is wrong)

Comment: Could an observer("small enough") fall into a black hole which is evaporating as fast as he/she is falling(**in his/her inertial frame)**? What would he/she observe?

Comment: @fielder: You might want to ask that as a separate question. That would be a full-on quantum gravity question, whereas this one is basically a classical gravity question. I doubt that anyone can say anything about your question given present lack of knowledge about a theory of quantum gravity.